# Trying to call the Scheduler API Methods but fails to work coming from Azure Mobile Service Job. Works locally

Tags: c#, security, azure, azure-mobile-services, x509certificate2

I have a console application that can delete and create jobs in a Job collection in Azure Scheduler. I have created a local certificate to create a SchedulerClient and have deployed this certificate to via the Azure Portal -> Settings -> Management Certificates -> Upload.

I have put the above code into a Scheduled Job within a Mobile Services App.

First the job failed as it states it can not find the certificate :-

> Message='Attempting to create scheduled job 'Job Name' failed with the
>   following message: 'A Certificate with Thumbprint 'xxxx' could not be
>   located.'.', Exception=System.ArgumentException: A Certificate with
>   Thumbprint 'xxxx' could not be located.    at
>   TechCare.Mobile.Services.JobManager.GetStoreCertificate(String
>   thumbprint)    at TechCare.Mobile.Services.JobManager..ctor()    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )    at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate(),
>   Id=6a06732a-1dba-4ce5-affe-dee1596877de,
>   Category='App.Controllers.Jobs'

So then I created a Base64String version of the certificate to which then this error was now returning

> Exception=Hyak.Common.CloudException: ForbiddenError: The server
>   failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is
>   valid and is associated with this subscription.    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Scheduler.JobOperationsExtensions.List(IJobOperations
>   operations, JobListParameters parameters)    at
>   TechCare.Mobile.Services.JobManager.ClearJobCollection()    at
>   techcaremobilewebservicesService.ScheduledJobs.dailyRoutines.CreateNotificationSchedule()
>   at
>   techcaremobilewebservicesService.ScheduledJobs.dailyRoutines.ExecuteAsync(),
>   Id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

So then I found a method to download a published profile from the Azure Portal and pulled out the string which makes up the management certificate from the file and tried that but that failed as well.

> Message='Attempting to create scheduled job 'Job Name' failed with the
>   following message: 'The system cannot find the file specified. '.',
>   Exception=System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet,
>   SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[]
>   rawData)    at
>   TechCare.Mobile.Services.JobManager.GetStoreCertificate(String
>   thumbprint), Id=31dd37b3-53cb-4f8b-8873-6155f25913dd,
>   Category='App.Controllers.Jobs'

To which I then found some flags that were suggested to add on when creating the certificate

> X509KeyStorageFlags flags = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
>   X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable;
>
> return new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certRaw), string.Empty,
>   flags);

But then this failed as well.

> Message='Attempting to create scheduled job 'Job Name' failed
>   with the following message: 'Access denied. '.',
>   Exception=System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access
>   denied.
>
> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet,
>   SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[]
>   rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   TechCare.Mobile.Services.JobManager.GetStoreCertificate(String
>   thumbprint), Id=07a6329b-f1ec-44b6-8446-12bcf616d336,
>   Category='App.Controllers.Jobs'

I would appreciate some help to fix this issue as I've spent more time trying to fix this than how long the actual development took :-S

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to authorize your Mobile Service to be able to manage your Scheduler Service. This requires a set of certificates because it would not be secure to do these management operations from user code.

See this document for more information: [Authenticating Service Management Requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460782.aspx)

Brady Gaster has a great step-by-step blog post on how to do this for Azure Websites, the procedure is similar for Mobile Services: [Managing Web Sites from Web Sites using the Azure Management Libraries for .NET](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/managing-web-sites-from-web-sites-using-the-windows-azure-management-libraries-for-net)

Comment: Excellent will have a look